# How to find routing table ID for VRF device using c-api in Linux

Tags: c, linux, routes

I would like to find association between VRF device and routing table id.

VRF device 'vrf-blue' is known, but table id '10' is needed for a struct rtmsg. 
[rtnetlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html)

```
# ip link add vrf-blue type vrf table 10

struct rtmsg {
    unsigned char       rtm_family;
    unsigned char       rtm_dst_len;
    unsigned char       rtm_src_len;
    unsigned char       rtm_tos;
    unsigned char       rtm_table;  /* Routing table id */
    unsigned char       rtm_protocol;   /* Routing protocol; see below  */
    unsigned char       rtm_scope;  /* See below */ 
    unsigned char       rtm_type;   /* See below    */
    unsigned        rtm_flags;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use detailed output option:

```
ip -d link show type vrf
```

Example output:

```
14: vrf5: <NOARP,MASTER> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5a:32:3b:9f:e9:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    vrf table 327 addrgenmode eui64    <----------------table id is 327
15: vrf6: <NOARP,MASTER> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:8f:8f:dc:13:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    vrf table 328 addrgenmode eui64
```